# How to plot a probability density function of 3 variables

Tags: python, plot, pythonplotter

I have some piecewise-constant probability density functions of 3 variables, and I would like to represent these on a 3D plot. My idea is to do this by leaving those grid cubes where p(x,y,z)=0 transparent, whilst increasing the opacity (or introducing some colouring, whichever looks better) for grid cubes with increasing p-value. In this way I hope to build a 3D object representing the "most likely" regions of space.

I can do this easily in 2D by making a coloured contour plot with MatPlotLib, but I haven't found any references for 3D versions.

Does anyone know if such a thing already exists? Or have any ideas?

Many thanks!
A.

Comment: Is this really a programming question? It seems more like a data presentation problem in the form that it's asked. Once you have decided what you want to do, ask for help with how to code what you want in a specific library.

Comment: Sorry, I had thought this was specific. Basically I want to make a 3D plot (ideally using the MatPlotLib for python library, which is what I am most used to, but at very least using some opensource software) which colours in grid squares with varying levels of opacity, dictated by some function (a PDF) p(x,y,z).